# The best solution for client-server separation of tasks

Tags: validation, security, client-server

I have an **application** that works with a **server**. In the application, you need to **fill out the forms** and submit them so that the **server writes this to the database**.

But I need to **validate** the entered **values** ​​as well.

If I check them in the application, it may be that the request sent from **someone else's program** (for example chrome) **will not check the values**.

But if I check everything on the server, it will **slow down**.

Is there a good solution, for example, to prohibit requests from other programs, or maybe everyone usually checks this on the server? or something else that I have not thought of.

*And in terms of http.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a good practice to validate your data on server side. It prevent cases you said just before.

But if you want to secure your access to your app, you can simply use an  authentication process on your server.

Checking user/pass or key or use OAuth protocol.
You can use more security with ip address checking,
A white/black list if you want.

So many possibilities. It depends on your needs

Comment: That is, an easy solution is to handle tasks of this kind on the server, and use the application as a "beautiful wrapper" for the user to communicate?